# Virtual Environment won't activate on Windows 10

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, windows-10, virtualenv

I use Windows 10, python 3.7.4 and i've installed virtualenv with pip. 
When i try to create virtual environment in cmd i can create with `virtualenv myenv.`It creates the files needed, Scripts folder and activate files are all there. But when i try to activate nothing happens. I try:

```
C:\Users\Spike\pyenv>cd crawler

C:\Users\Spike\pyenv\crawler>cd scripts

C:\Users\Spike\pyenv\crawler\Scripts>activate
```

After this virtual environment name should be in parenthesis like this:

```
(crawler) C:\Users\Spike\pyenv\crawler\Scripts
```

but it is not, virtual env is not activated, it continues like this:

```
C:\Users\Spike\pyenv\crawler\Scripts>
```

I've tried running cmd in admin mode, doesn't work.

I've tried to activate from Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Spike\pyenv\crawler> cd scripts
PS C:\Users\Spike\pyenv\crawler\scripts> activate
```

But i get a error:

```
activate : The term 'activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ activate
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

So i've tried Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned and Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force on Powershell before activating it, it also doesn't work.

I've also tried to activate it in cmder, i get the same result i got in cmd.

To solve i first looked in to other stackoverflow thread but none helped.

Comment: What is the output from `Dir /B/S/A-D "C:\activate.bat"`, entered in the Windows Command Prompt? Or `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:" -File -Filter "activate.bat" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse`, at the PowerShell Prompt?

Comment: Sounds like maybe yours is working; but a couple things since I've been having problems - for Powershell, you'd want to find a script named Activate.ps1.  And for cmd, I would have expected you to need activate.bat.    For me, I got stuck by the normal tools -- I could activate env, put pip didn't work.  I found a different powershell tool that is working well so far -- https://github.com/regisf/virtualenvwrapper-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of your virtualenv. You said the name of your env was myenv. However, you are in the pyenv directory. If you CD to the folder you where in when you created myenv, the following should work.

```
myenv/Sripts/activate
```

If that does not work, make sure the activate file is actually there.

Also, note that in certain cases the virtualenv starts but you don't get the (myenv) bahavior. Run the following to see if the virtualenv is activated.

```
which python
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, i gave `myenv` as an example. I've created this environment in a folder called pyenv with `virtualenv crawler`, my activate files are there. 

`which python` in cmder returns: `/c/Users/Spike/pyenv/crawler/Scripts/python` so my virtualenv is working i guess?

Comment: Yes. It looks like your environment is active then.